# Can swap be used instead of RAM?

Tags: ssd, swap, memory-usage

I have an older netbook that I love. It's currently using a relatively recent version of Lubuntu. The hangup is its relatively low amount of onboard RAM: 1GB. This amount also cannot be updated as it is soldered to the motherboard.

If I were to upgrade its internal hard drive to a speedy SSD, would I be able to tune Ubuntu to prioritize it as a source of system memory? If so, how would I approach this during a fresh install?

I understand that swap will never be as fast as onboard RAM, but does this sound like a fair workaround?

Feel free to add any information of software and other platforms with regard to this problem as well.

Comment: no. probably...

Comment: Totally without any RAM your notebook won't be able to run anything. But maybe a really fast Drive can reduce the amount of time to copy enough for your needs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best you can do is to shange `swappiness` parameter

The `swappiness` parameter configures how often your system swaps data out of `RAM` to the `swap` space. This is a value between `0` and `100` that represents a percentage.

With values close to zero, the kernel will not swap data to the disk unless absolutely necessary. Remember, interactions with the swap file are "expensive" in that they take a lot longer than interactions with RAM and they can cause a significant reduction in performance. Telling the system not to rely on the `swap` much will generally make your system faster.

Values that are closer to `100` will try to put more data into `swap` in an effort to keep more `RAM` space free.

We can see the current `swappiness` value by typing:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
60
```

For a Desktop, a `swappiness` setting of `60` is not a bad value.

We can set the `swappiness` to a different value by using the `sysctl` command.

For instance, to set the `swappiness` to `90`, we could type:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=90
vm.swappiness = 90
```

This setting will persist until the next reboot. We can set this value automatically at restart by adding the line to our `/etc/sysctl.conf` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

At the bottom, you can add:

```
vm.swappiness=90
```

Save and close the file when you are finished.